# Proper organize classes in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, oop

im writing server for a game in node.js.

I have problem with a proper construction. For example I have this code:

```
class mob {
    constructor(name) {
      this.name = name;
      this.health = 100;
    }
    getHealth() {
      return this.health;
    }
}

class items{
    constructor(name, id) {
      this.name = name;
      this.id= id;
      this.value= value;
    }
    getValue() {
      return this.value;
    }
}

 class world {
    constructor(name) {
      this.name = name;
      this.weather = 'rain';
      this.monsters = {};
    }

   addMonster(name) {
     const monster = new mob(name);
     this.monsters['1'] = monster;
   }

   setWeather(weather) {
     this.weather = weather;
   }
   play() {
     this.addMonster('dragon');

   }
 }

game = new world;
game.play();
```

And I would like manipulate weather inside a world class, without duplicating it in monster class using for example code like this:
`monster.setWeather('snow');`

Other than that after I would like to add new classes like items, map objects etc. inside a world class and manipulate them with functions inside world class. for ex:
`item.setWeather('rainbow');` and also manipulate class on other classes like `monster.getItemValue('item')`
Whats the proper way of doing this in javascript?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). I'm afraid this is much too broad and open-ended for SO's Q&A format. I suggest working through some basic JavaScript tutorials and/or a good beginner's book to learn the basics.

Comment: Just as a side note: `this.monsters['1'] = monster;` isn't the correct way to *add* to the `monsters` array; it always puts a monster at index 1 (leaving index 0 and indexes 2 onward unoccupied). To add an entry to an array, you typically use the [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method: `this.monsters.push(new mob(name));`, although you see things like `this.monsters[this.monsters.length] = new mob(name);` as well (I don't recommend that).

Comment: Also, the overwhelming convention in JavaScript is that the names of *constructor functions* (like your `mob`, `items`, and `world`) start with a capital letter; so, `Mob`, `Items`, and `World`. Finally, note that all of the properties of an object are inherently public, so there's no need for `getHealth`, `getValue`, or `setWeather`; you can just use `health`, `value`, and `weather` directly. ([Private fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) will be added to `class` syntax soon. They aren't properties, although they're similar.)

Comment: Right, of course good points. Thanks for corrections!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand correctly.

As you have a global variable "game" already, you can use "game.setWeather()" directly.

Comment: Right, but I would like to manipulate that way inside a world (game) class .

Comment: I would like something like this:
`
class mob {
    constructor(name) {
      this.name = name;
      this.health = 100;
    }
    getHealth() {
      return this.health;
    }
    setWeather(weather) {
        game.setWeather(weather)
    }

}
`
but then i get an error that game is not a declared object.

Comment: Ok, your solution its ok, the problem is propably bacause I use two separate files then I cannot use it in that way.